# MooTools: How to use responseText directly

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools1.2

In following example of code, I want to traverse the responseText object which consist the html code came from request_page.php file. In onSuccess event, i want to check whether < Div > with id 'ersDiv' has any errors posted in it.

```
new Request.HTML({
    url: 'request_page.php',
    onSuccess: function(responseText, responseXML) {
    // My expected code to handle responseText object
    alert(errorMessage);
    },
    onFailure: function() {  }
});
```

request_page.php file is like this :

```
<div align='center'><div id='ersDiv'>Page loaded with insufficient data</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for 1.2.x (example tweaked for the jsfiddle api):

```
new Request.HTML({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    method: "post",
    data: {
        html: "<div align='center'><div id='ersDiv'>Page loaded with insufficient data</div></div>",
        delay: 1
    },
    onComplete: function(responseText, responseXML) {
        var error, errors = responseXML.getElements("div").filter(function(el) {
            return el.get("id") == "ersDiv";
        });

        if (errors.length) {
            error = errors[0].get("text");
            alert(error);
        }
    }
}).send();
```

working example:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/vLgqB/

in 1.3 this can work as oskar suggested:

```
console.log($$(this.response.tree).getElement("#ersDiv")[0].get("text"));
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/vLgqB/2/

have fun.

Answer (score 1):

```
function(responseText, responseXML) {
  if (responseText.getElement('#ersDiv').get('text') === 'Page loaded with insufficient data'){
    console.log('There was an error');
  }
}
```

Btw. 1990 called, they want their `align='center'`'s back :-)

Comment: Even if i put alert() its not working : function(responseText, responseXML) {
  alert(responseText.getElement('#ersDiv').get('text'));
}

Comment: in 1.2.5 this was somewhat dodgy (iirc) - check my reply with .filter